# How to limit file size in multipart request in aiohttp python?

Tags: python, multipart, aiohttp

I need to make a multipart request using aiohttp python. But I would like to limit a file size; say 10 MB if client side tried to fire multipart request with more than 10 MB then code suppose to throw an error. as well I would like get file format and want to set multipart request timeout. How one can achieve it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think `nginx` (or another frontend/proxy web-server) would be a better place to limit the request size.